# Using Paypal in a production and staging enviorment

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I am getting ready to "go live" on my [Paypal REST app](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/), but I want to still be able to continue developing new features like one touch. I understand that as soon as I go live I no longer have access to the sandbox for this app. If so, how do I continue to make calls from my staging environment with "play" money?

One solution I had in mind is simply to use 2 separate paypal apps, and never go live on one. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really lose access to using sandbox credentials even after you go live. So you can definitely have two apps, one with sandbox credentials/and other with live credentials.

Can you share more details about your development environment? Even after you go live, you can still keep testing in your local environment using the PayPal sandbox credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I will just "go live" and see if I can continue using the sandbox in my staging environment. If not I will create another app for staging.